# How to apply boosting in solr for keywords from txt(or config) file

Tags: solr, lucene, relevance

I am new in solr world, please help me in boosting keywords.

I have a keywords.txt file with 100 words. For example:

```
foo^1.1 
bar^0.9
test^0.1
wings^0.9
```

How can I add this file to Solr? I'm looking for a way similar to synonyms.txt, stopwords.txt, protwords.txt or spellings.txt file.

For example, if I want to find all docs matching "foo" or "bar". I would like to send to Solr query

```
q = foo bar

q = foo^1.1 bar^0.9    # NOT WHAT I WANT
```

Comment: cant you add these to solrconfig.xml?

Comment: I thought about solrconfig.xml. But I would like to update those 100 keywords once per day automatically and it will be quite difficult to do it in solrconfig.xml.

Comment: Then in this case you may need to handle it programmatically...